# How do I re-use a helper function in Angular testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, frontend, protractor

In my unit test (written with protractor) I need to write functions that should be used in several tests in several files (and only in unit tests).

How can I create those functions?

The best solution is to declare the functions in a single file to include in the test files that I need, but I don't know how to do it without creating global variables or global functions.

Comment: Are you sure these are unit tests? Protractor is usually used for end-to-end tests. Can you post the code from one of them?

Comment: Thanks for reporting it, I didn't note that error due to the copy-past (I prepared the document in another editor). I have the same problem on unit test (written with karma) and in e2e test (written in protractor). Now I still have problem just in the unit test.

Answer (score 2):

If you would follow the [Page Object pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html), you would not be in a situation like this. All of the functions you need would be tied to page objects, you would have a nice separation of concerns and any changes in the element selection logic would be like a breeze. You can also think about page objects as global libraries available in your tests.

See also how can you apply the pattern using `protractor`:

- [Using Page Objects to Organize Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md#using-page-objects-to-organize-tests)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you let me fix my issues on e2e test, I still have the same problem for the unit test.